# Extended access tokens for pages without user administrator

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-page

I am wondering if it is possible to obtain an extended access token for facebook pages that do not have a facebook profile set as it's administrator.  I see it is possible to create a facebook page without setting a user profile as the admin and having those pages auth with my app.

For pages that do have a facebook profile as it's administrator, I am able to extend the short lived access token when requesting the manage_pages permission. But I'm not if there is no user associated with it.

The documentation describes this process for extending page tokens.

> Apps can retrieve a Page access token from Page admin users when they
>   authenticate with the manage_pages permission. If the user access
>   token used to retrieve this Page access token is short-lived, the Page
>   access token will also be short-lived.
>
> To get a longer-lived Page access token, exchange the User access
>   token for a long-lived one, as above, and then request the Page token.
>   The resulting Page access token will not have an expiry time at all.

[Extending Access Tokens Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/)

I am wondering if it's possible to obtain extended access tokens for pages when there is no admin associated with the page.

Comment: What do you mean 'a page without a profile as its administrator'? that isn't possible - all pages must be owned by a user account, either a regular user account or a business account - and both work in the same way as far as the API is concerned

Comment: I thought this too.  But apparently not, it's possible to create a facebook page without having the page owned by a user account.  If you go to Facebook without being logged in, you'll see this where you can create a page without ever associating it with a user: 


[screenshot](http://f.cl.ly/items/2V12131c1i2k0q3f3v1F/Screen%20Shot%202013-04-23%20at%209.01.33%20AM.png)

Comment: That creates a business account which becomes the sole admin of the page - business accounts can use the API, grant access to manage their pages, and use the page management APIs the same way as any regular user account

Comment: Right exactly.  But I can't seem to obtain an extended access token for 'Business accounts.'  Do you know if this is at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

All pages must be owned by a user account, either a regular user account or a business account - and both work in the same way as far as the API is concerned, at least for login (business accounts don't have names, a timeline, friends, etc so are obviously not the exact same, but they log in and grant access to apps the same way)

I just tested a few minutes ago using the my app, a business account and the [server side oauth flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/) and received a long expiry (approx 60 day) token correctly when exchanging the business account's code for an access token

I was then able go through the flow again, this time asking for `manage_pages` permission and was able to use the token to retrieve a non-expiring page access token for a page the account manages using the regular process (a call to `/me/accounts` or `/?fields=access_token)

Comment: That makes sense that all pages should are owned by either a user or business account.  However I'm still unable to get a non-expiring access token for my app.  Going through the server side oauth flow. First off I receive a short expiry (1 hour) token for the Business user.  Maybe this is the first place it goes wrong?  Then going through the second time requesting manage_pages, to obtain page access_token it stays at 1 hour.

Comment: Alright I think I'm making progress. I was able to get an extended access token with my test application.  Unfortunately I'm not able to with my Production app.  Do you know if there's a reason this would happen? Are we violating some terms which limit us to short access tokens?

Comment: No, but if your user (the business account) has already authorised your production app in the distant past they may need to remove and re-add it to get a long token

Comment: Hmm, do you know if obtaining an extended access token can be limited by spam reports for your app? I've been unable to get to the bottom of why our app is being limited in obtaining these extended access tokens.  Is it possible to get in touch directly with someone on the platform team about this?

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you're saying isn't working - if you have a reproducible bug please file a bug report in Facebook's bug tracker, if you haven't already deauthorised the app, then gone through the **server-side** auth flow again, try that first before compiling repro steps for a bug report

Comment: Thanks Igy.  I've deauthed the app and gone through the flow quite a few times, but no dice.  The only way the flow works is if I use different application credentials.  

I've created the bug report here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/638335569525430  

Seems a couple other users are seeing the same issue.  Alvin has closed the ticket suggesting we make a call to setExtendedAccessToken(), but we already do that.  I've mentioned this, and included the repro steps so hoping he reopens the ticket.